# Why are the values of these two numbers not equal?

Tags: javascript

Having some trouble understanding why my numbers aren't giving me the correct equality in javascript.

I inserted a vector of numbers into an array in javascript...

```
const seen = [ 
                [0,1] 
              ];
console.log(contains(seen, [0,1]));
```

And then tried to do a simple comparison

```
    const contains = function(arr, coordinate){
        arr.forEach(element => {
            if(element[0] == coordinate[0] && element[1] == coordinate[1]){
         

       return true;
        }
    })

    return false;
}
```

Im expecting my contains function to return true. Element is [0,1] and the coordinate im comparing to is also [0,1], yet when I try to compare with the following:

```
element[0] == coordinate[0] && element[1] == coordinate[1]
```

It ultimately returns false.

Full code:

```js
const contains = function(arr, coordinate) {
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (element[0] === coordinate[0] && element[1] === coordinate[1]) {
      return true;
    }
  })

  return false;
}

const seen = [
  [0, 1]
];
console.log(contains(seen, [0, 1]))
```

Comment: You're returning `true` from the `forEach()` callback, not from `contains()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the forEach to a normal for. Right now return is returning only from the lambda.

```
const contains = function(arr, coordinate) {
    for (const element of arr) {
        if(element[0] == coordinate[0] && element[1] == coordinate[1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```